# Unity: How to instantiate a prefab by string name to certain location?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I saved all the string names in a List to save all the prefab vehicles that the player owns.

The string names are the prefab names.

**How would I go by on spawning/ instantiating the prefab by name?**

And to spawn the prefab on a specific location or on a game object?

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```cs
List<string> playerOwnPrefabNames;
GameObject someGameObject;

foreach(prefabName in playerOwnPrefabNames)
{
    var prefabName = playerOwnPrefabNames;
    var prefabInstance = Instantiate(Resources.Load(pathOfPrefabDirectory+prefabName)) as GameObject;
}
```

Then, to spawn the prefab on `someGameObject`(this will make the instantiated prefab as a child of `someGameObject`):

```cs
prefabInstance.SetParent(someGameObject.transform);
```

To move the prefab to a specific location:

```cs
prefabInstance.transform.position = new Vector3(100, 200, 100);
```

Reference:

- [Object.Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html)
- [Resources.Load](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html)
- [Transform.SetParent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html)

Comment: Instead of using `SetParent` you can declare a parent in the `Instantiate` command. This avoids 2 transform hierarchy recalculations (which can be costly).

Answer (score 2):

I have tested this [answer](https://forum.unity.com/threads/editor-script-create-game-object-from-a-prefab.47845/#post-304657), it works.

```cs
var prefab = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath("Assets/Units/Human/Footman/Footman.prefab", typeof(GameObject));
GameObject clone = Instantiate(prefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

clone.transform.position = Vector3.one;
```